# Enabling geodatabase in AWS RDS PostgreSQL instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Superuser permission is required to create a geodatabase in PostgreSQL.

However, in AWS RDS instance we are receiving:

> rds_superuser permission and rds_superuser is not superuser.

**Is there a way to enable geodatabase in AWS RDS PostgreSQL with rds_superuser permission?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the database and the sde login manually using e.g. pgAdmin, and grant the rds_superuser group role to the sde login. Also create a schema named sde in your database, and make the sde login the owner of that schema.

Then you can create a .sde database connection in ArcCatalog using the sde login and, importantly, the *.rds.amazonaws.com hostname. Finally you can run the Enable Enterprise Geodatabase using this connection as your input.

This only works if you connect to the database using the *.rds.amazonaws.com hostname. Apparently, ESRI uses the hostname to determine if the database in question is an RDS server.

Once you've enabled the geodatabase you can connect to it with .sde connections using other dns aliases as well.

Refer to the ESRI documentation for further details: http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/cloud/amazon/create-geodatabase-in-amazon-rds-for-postgresql.htm